# How do I tell if any values have changed for NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a typical case of implementing a preference panel for my application, but I've run into a problem with detecting changes to any preference values. In my case I don't want to apply changes automatically so I've set

```
[[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController] setAppliesImmediately:NO];
```

I've also bound all my controls in my preference panel to **sharedUserDefaultsController**.

And then I have a Cancel and a Apply button in my preference panel, and I want to only enable the Apply button if any changes had been made to the **sharedUserDefaultsController** values.

So I thought I could bind **hasUnappliedChanges** of my **sharedUserDefaultsController** to my Apply buttons enable property. But **hasUnappliedChanges** only return **true**, even if no changes have been made. Or actually it returns **false** as long as I do not load my preference panel window. But as soon as the window is loaded and it reaches **awakeFromNib**, **hasUnappliedChanges** returns **true**. And from there on I can't get it to reset back to **false**. Doesn't matter if I save the **sharedUserDefaultsController**.

So my questions are:

- How do you properly detect if any values of **sharedUserDefaultsController** has changed?
- And does **hasUnappliedChanges** work when you bind your controls to **sharedUserDefaultsController**?

Appreciate any help I can get.

---

**Edit**

I tried observing **NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification**, but that only post an update after a value is saved to the user defaults. In other words, after I call

```
[(NSUserDefaultsController*)[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController] save:sender];
```

So unless I'm using this wrong way that wont work as far as I can tell.

Comment: It appears that you need send an "`applyChanges:` message," according to [this reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/NSUserDefaultsController.html) though I don't see that as an instance method.  Perhaps they mean `commitEditing`?

Comment: Yes I've read the reference, but I think applyChanges is a typo and I thought they meant save (I've actually sent feedback to Apple about it). I haven't tried commitEditing. I'll give it a try and see if it helpes. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, `save` may be what they meant. `commitEditing` is an NSControl instance method.  I see now you mention doing the `save`.  My first instinct is that applies-not-immediately and bindings are incompatible, because bindings always reflect the datamodel, but you think they'd bother to mention that in the reference.

Comment: commitEditing didn't do the trick. And to be frank I'm at loss as to how the NSUserDefaultsController hasUnappliedChanges work. It would be so sweet if it worked the way I thought but apparently it doesn't so I guess I'll just have to work around it. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: I personally post my own notifications whenever I make changes to the defaults, rather than relying on anything built in to cocoa to do it. If you write the code yourself... you will understand how it works. Tends to be fewer bugs that way.

Comment: I guess I'll have to go that route if no one comes up with a better solution. But the whole point of having a framework is so you don't have to invent the wheel every time, right?

Comment: Are there preset values in the nib that are being set in awakeFromNib and that don't match the values in the defaults before awakeFromNib is called ?

Comment: Also when/where is the binding... code or nib ?

Comment: No, no preset values are set in awakeFromNib.
The bindings are setup in the nib.